# Programming> Extract Rows where the list items match the column values

Tags: r

```
l <- c("a","b","c")
```

`m` is a 5x2 data frame. `C1` is `1:5`, `C2` is `a:e`:

```
m <- data.frame(C1 = 1:5, C2 = letters[1:5], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to find `n`, where it contains only those rows of `m` where `m$C2` is in the values stated in `l`

The resulting `n` is a 3x2 such that C2 is `a:c`, i.e.

```
  C1 C2
1  1  a
2  2  b
3  3  c
```

Comment: I presume you meant data frame as a matrix can't hold `1:5` as numeric **and** `letters[1:5]` as characters at the same time. matrices are atomic in R (i.e. of a single type of data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to do the matching by hand with `%in%`:

```
m <- data.frame(C1 = 1:5, C2 = letters[1:5], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
l <- c("a","b","c")

with(m, m[C2 %in% l, ])

R> with(m, m[C2 %in% l, ])
  C1 C2
1  1  a
2  2  b
3  3  c
```

Or alternatively via the `match()` function:

```
R> m[with(m, match(C2, l, nomatch = FALSE)), ]
  C1 C2
1  1  a
2  2  b
3  3  c
```

where the `nomatch` argument is required to get rid of the `NA` rows.